# Is a parameterized java persistence query susceptible to sql injections?

Tags: sql, sql-injection, hsqldb, jpql

For eg. i have:

```
Input:
ArrayList<Integer> idlist
String nameText

    String q = "DELETE FROM myTable AS a WHERE a.name LIKE '%' || :name || '%' OR a.id IN (:idlist)";

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(q);
    query.setParameter("name", nameText);
    query.setParameter("idlist", idlist);

query.executeUpdate();
```

Would the above snippet of code susceptible to sql injections?
I have one more question is there a diffrence between the way above query is built and if we form query by criterias:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

  CriteriaQuery<Country> q = cb.createQuery(Country.class);
  Root<Country> c = q.from(Country.class);
  q.select(c);
```

Is there any advantage of one over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it wouldn't. That's the whole point of parameterized queries.

Comment: I have one more question is there a diffrence between the way above query is built and if we form query by criterias... i mean createSelect, something like that?

Comment: No. The Criteria API also uses JDBC prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance for SQL injection with prepared statements.

But if the values of parameter are entered by users, the expression `LIKE % || :name || %` can be misused by entering only one letter and deleting all the records that contain that letter anywhere in the a.name column